# Comment parler des décennies ? — How to refer to decades verbally ?

Tags: nombres, indications-de-temps, dates

En anglais, on dit, par exemple, "the eighties" pour se référer aux années 1980-1990 (ou à la culture, la musique...). Quels sont les équivalents en français ? En particulier, sont-ils différents en Belgique et Suisse (où on ne dit pas les même nombres) ?

---

In English, we say, e.g, "the eighties" to refer to the years 1980-1990 (or the culture, or the music, ...). What is the French phrase? In particular, what is said in Belgium and Switzerland,  where the numbers are different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les *eighties* (mot souvent aussi employé en français) sont les années quatre-vingts. En Belgique, elles sont entourées des années septante et nonante. Dans certaines régions de Suisse, comme par exemple la ville de Lausanne, on parle des années huitante.

Note: "[Décade](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cade)" est controversé en français et considéré comme un anglicisme. "Décennie" qui ne présente pas d’ambiguïté lui est préféré. "Décade" désignait une période de dix jours sous le calendrier républicain.

Comment: Si j'en crois le TLFi, l'utilisation de _décade_ pour une période de dix ans précède l'usage qui en a été fait dans le calendrier républicain.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Réponse mise à jour.

Answer (score 12):

En Français, pour se référer aux années 1980-1990 on dira ''les années 80''.
Par exemple : ''La musique des années 70''.

In French, when referring to the eighties, we say ''Les années 80''